# Can this PHP statement with a isset() check be simplified?

Tags: php

Needing to check whether the item exists in the array and either add to it or increase the value by the amount.

```
if(isset($this->_costRemovedByLineItem[$objectId])) {
    $this->_costRemovedByLineItem[$objectId] += $amount;
}else{
    $this->_costRemovedByLineItem[$objectId] = $amount;
}
```

I have a feeling this can be simplified.

Comment: What version of PHP?

Comment: Instead of trying to "simplify", go for code readability, you'll thank yourself later. Imho also go ahead and add a check for if is that property an array or not and add a handling for that scenario, cause php ain't letting you set an index for a boolean, now is it. 1 more vector of error squashed.

Answer (score 7):

This method reduces it a bit, as you don't need the else statement or to assign amount twice.

```
if(!isset($this->_costRemovedByLineItem[$objectId])) {
    $this->_costRemovedByLineItem[$objectId] = 0;
}
$this->_costRemovedByLineItem[$objectId] += $amount;
```

Answer (score 7):

Something that will work in all versions of PHP:

```
@$this->_costRemovedByLineItem[$objectId] += $amount;
```

The `@` ([error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)) will cause PHP to ignore the error caused by the non-existent index, create the element (with an empty value) and then add `$amount` to it, resulting in a value of `$amount` (as the empty value gets converted to 0 as a number).

> **Warning** use of the `@` operator could potentially make it harder to debug
>   your code, as it will hide error messages that you may have
>   needed to see (for example, even if `$this` doesn't exist, or there is
>   no object element called `_costRemovedByLineItem`, PHP will create
>   them along with the array). See the third case in my example code.

Alternatively in PHP7 you can use the [`Null Coalescing Operator`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
$this->_costRemovedByLineItem[$objectId] = ($this->_costRemovedByLineItem[$objectId] ?? 0) + $amount;
```

And in PHP < 7 you can use the [`ternary operator`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
$this->_costRemovedByLineItem[$objectId] = (isset($this->_costRemovedByLineItem[$objectId]) ? $this->_costRemovedByLineItem[$objectId] : 0) + $amount;
```

A shorter example of each:

```
$amount = 4;
@$a[5] += $amount;
print_r($a);
$b[6] = ($b[6] ?? 0) + $amount;
print_r($b);
@$c->x[5] += $amount;
print_r($c);
$d[3] = (isset($d[3]) ? $d[3] : 0) + $amount;
print_r($d);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [5] => 4 ) 
Array ( [6] => 4 )
stdClass Object (
    [x] => Array ( [5] => 4 ) 
)
Array ( [3] => 4 )
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/tNV3s)

Comment: Now that is nice

Comment: The null coalescing example is great imho, but the first example can be really problematic when debugging.  I'd never recommend using `@`.  What if _costRemovedByLineItem is deleted, or is an object.  The code will fail without any error in anything under 7.1: https://3v4l.org/pvvrX

Comment: @Devon the failure in your demo occurs when `_costRemovedByLineItem` is an object, but if it is OPs code will also fail as they are trying to use it as an array too.

Comment: That was my point. But in php 5.6 it's a silent failure, meaning you'd have no idea where the problem is. In a large project, you can never guarantee a property will remain the same long term. If someone changes the property or the property isn't what you think, the app may break and this  makes it incredibly hard to track down.

Comment: @Devon you are right, but we are talking about a hypothetical change of a variable from an array to an object which would require a complete code rewrite. As long as the variable remains an array it works fine in all versions of PHP https://3v4l.org/ZhhhO

Comment: @Nick, in a large project with multiple contributors, you don't always have the ability to foresee changes like this is my point.   If your project has 100,000 lines of code in 500 files, and a piece of core functionality breaks and you can't figure out where it's breaking because someone hid the error, it can become a problem that causes lots of lost money or time.  (Way more costly than writing an additional line of code)